# пример отталвивания объектов друг от друга?

Tags: three.js

Есть ли где-нибудь пример столкновения объектов с использованием PhysicsJS

как  в примере http://www.geofx.com/graphics/nehe-three-js/lessons25-32/lesson30/lesson30webgl.html

У меня также есть около 20 объектов, только это не mesh, а загружаемые объекты. Мне нужно, чтобы они отталкивались друг от друга если при движении вдруг пересеклись

Comment: `только это не mesh, а загружаемые объекты` - загруженные объекты уже автоматически `THREE.Mesh()`, либо являются дочерними элементами объекта типа `THREE.Group()`, но даже тут они имеют тип `THREE.Mesh()` либо `THREE.SkinnedMesh()`. Зависит от того - какой загрузчик применяется.

Comment: использую FBX loader и obj loader.
Могу ли я применить метод, описанный тут
http://www.geofx.com/graphics/nehe-three-js/lessons25-32/lesson30/lesson30.html

или легче библиотеку подключить какую-то?

Comment: Cобственно, этот же метод используется в примере, приведенном в вопросе :)